# How get a static block content based on its title not identifier?

Tags: static-block

I wanted to get in product page a sizing chart. I could do that very easy but I want to improve and need some help. So, I created a drop down attribute called size_chart with the following values which identify my static blocks:

- addidas_shoes
- puma_shoes
- nike_shoes

Choosing an option from the list I can get the right static block. Now I would like to change the drop down values to block titles instead of block id's for a better visual improvement, like this:

- Adidas Shoes
- Puma Shoes
- Nike Shoes

How can I get inside my phtml template the block content based on its title instead of its identifier? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to identify your static block by its title. What i understood is that you want to improve the "dropdown experience" for your users, displaying block title instead of block id. In your phtml file you can do something like that:

```
<select>
  <option value="addidas_shoes">Adidas Shoes</option>
  <option value="puma_shoes">Puma Shoes</option>
  <option value="nike_shoes">Nike Shoes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This change is available for Backend not Frontend. I need to achieve having in a drop down list block title instead of block id. If this is not possible I will let it as it is.